# Put whisker ends on boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to put perpendicular lines at the ends of the whiskers like the `boxplot` function automatically gives.

Comment: you can do this by calculating the quantile where ggplot draws the lines and drawing your own `geom_segment` or `geom_crossbar`. see [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8137/how-to-add-horizontal-lines-to-ggplot2-boxplot)

Comment: Is there some reason why this must be done in ggplot2, and not using `boxplot` which already does what you want, or is this question of purely academic interest...?

Comment: @Justin Thanks, I've checked out that question but it's too advanced for me and I keep getting errors, I don't know which bits to replace with what, sorry :/

Comment: @Jake It's purely aesthetic! I have an assignment requiring 2 graphs, one boxplot, one interaction graph.  I've created the interaction graph in ggplot2, and would like the boxplot to be consistent (with the axes labels close up to the tick mark labels)....

Comment: @Jake @ Justin Alternatively, is there a way I can move the position of the axes labels in base boxplot so that they are closer to the tick mark labels and in bold? I'm sure I'm being too pernickety, but I would like the graphs to be consistent.

Comment: @Jake @ Justin  Maybe I wouldn't lose marks for the ggplot2 boxplot not having ends on the whiskers but I just think with the ends on the whiskers is a more traditional boxplot, and it's easier to figure out what the amounts are with the ends on them.  Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 72):

As hinted but not implemented by @Roland, you can use `stat_boxplot` to implement this. The trick calling `_boxplot` twice and is to set the `geom` to `errorbar` for one of the calls.

Note that as `R` uses a pen and paper approach it is advisable to implement the error bars first the  draw the traditional boxplot over the top.

Using @Roland's dummy data `df`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y = value))  + 
 stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
 geom_boxplot() # shorthand for  stat_boxplot(geom='boxplot')
```

[image]

The help for [`stat_boxplot`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_boxplot.html) (`?stat_boxplot`) detail  the various values computed and saved in a `data.frame`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this! :)

Comment: how can I resize these whisker-lines if I use `geom_boxplot(width=.2)` ?

Comment: @ Produnis To resize the whiskers lines add the argument `stat_params = list(width = 0.5)` inside the function: `stat_boxplot`. See the result in my answer.

Comment: @Produnis and others. Currently:  ``geom_boxplot(width = 0.2) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2)``, where the values selected in the boxplot and in the error bars must match. For whiskers that span half the box, you would set ``width = 0.2`` and ``width = 0.1``.

Answer (score 39):

To resize the whiskers lines we can use the argument `width = 0.5` inside the function: `stat_boxplot`

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 500)), 
                 value = c(rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = 0.2), 
                           rnorm(500, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.1))) 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = cond, y = value)) +
       stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +  
       geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me; I get `Error: Unknown parameters: stat_params`. What version of R are you using?

Comment: @Will I modified the answer. The new version ggplo2 2.0.0 doesn't accept that argument `stat_params` . Now it should work.

Comment: One thing to note though is that this solution puts the error bars on top of the box, which is a bit odd; is there a way of having the vertical bar not run on top of the box?

Comment: Awesome! Obvious now that I think about it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried using this nice code in combination with a "fill" statement for subgroup coloring. It works without setting width, but with the width setting it unfortunately leads to weird effects.

Comment: In order to avoid the error bars on top of the box I did `stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') +
geom_boxplot(inherit.aes = TRUE)`

Comment: @Facottons I do not get your point. The default argument for `inherit.aes` is TRUE, so `geom_boxplot(inherit.aes = TRUE)` and `geom_boxplot()` are identical.

Answer (score 8):

It might be possible to use `stat_boxplot` to calculate the whisker ends, but I am not enough of a `ggplot2` wizard, so I use the base function for that.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=500) ), 
                 value = c(rnorm(500,mean=1,sd=0.2),rnorm(500, mean=1.5,sd=0.1)))


whisk <- function(df,cond_col=1,val_col=2) {
  require(reshape2)
  condname <- names(df)[cond_col]
  names(df)[cond_col] <- "cond" 
  names(df)[val_col] <- "value"
  b <- boxplot(value~cond,data=df,plot=FALSE)
  df2 <- cbind(as.data.frame(b$stats),c("min","lq","m","uq","max"))
  names(df2) <- c(levels(df$cond),"pos")
  df2 <- melt(df2,id="pos",variable.name="cond")
  df2 <- dcast(df2,cond~pos)  
  names(df2)[1] <- condname
  df2
}



library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=cond)) 
plot1 <- plot1 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),data=whisk(df),width = 0.5)
plot1 <- plot1 + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value))
plot1
```

[image: boxplot with horizontal at whisker ends]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of [`ggplot2 v3.5.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0/) we can now use the `staplewidth` argument in `geom_boxplot` to add some whiskers to the ends. According to the documentation:

> The relative width of staples to the width of the box. Staples mark
> the ends of the whiskers with a line.

So with staplewidth of 0 we don't have whiskers. Here is some reproducible example:

```r
# Install latest version
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y = Sepal.Length))  + 
  geom_boxplot(staplewidth = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>