# how to change the width of stat_boxplot (errorbar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 for box ploting.
However, I can't change the width of stat_boxplot (geom ='errorbar').
Here is part of my code:

```
geom_boxplot(width=0.5)+stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar',width=0.5)
```

It's OK for `geom_boxplot()`, but the width of `stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')` is not changed .
Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: file a bug report, in the meanwhile you can use the second solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993545/how-to-put-whisker-ends-on-ggplot2-boxplot/13003038

Answer (score 5):

To resize the whiskers lines (width) we can use the argument `stat_params = list(width = 0.5)` inside the function: `stat_boxplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(factor(Species), Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', stat_params = list(width = 0.5)) +
```

**Update**

[Now](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/stat_boxplot.html) we can use the argument `width` inside `stat_boxplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(factor(Species), Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This no longer works for newer version ggplot2. `stat_boxplot` has `width` parameter now.