# Adjust boxplot arm width, and add horizontal lines to the bottom and top

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created an image with ggplot2. Code is listed below:

```
ggplot(aes(y = SCORE, x = DATE, fill = CATEGORY), data = data_R1000) 
+ geom_boxplot(width=0.6,position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),outlier.size = 0, size = 0.5)
+ ylim(20,100) + labs(title = "US_MARKETOR") + theme(legend.position="bottom") 
+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)) 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
+ scale_fill_hue(c=50, l=85)
```

the result looks like below[image]

now, i will have to make the arm of box plots thicker, that is, the vertical lines above and beneath the bar. I have tried adjust the 'size = 2', but this gives me a thicker line for the entire box plot.

[image]

this is definitely not what I want, and I am having trouble in making only the arm part thicker. Please let me know if there is a way I can do this.

***in addition, if there is no way to do this, how can I add a horizontal line and the top and bottom of the arms? (Just like the normal box plot generated without using ggplot2)

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I believe there is no way to do either of these tasks in `ggplot2` alone; you'll have to go into `grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whisker ends can be done like this:
[How to put whisker ends on ggplot2 boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993545/how-to-put-whisker-ends-on-ggplot2-boxplot)

If you just want to make the vertical lines thicker... I"m not sure. I agree with Drew. Probably have to resort to some geom_segment() or pure grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. In addition, do you know how can we adjust the size of error bar? how can I make it shorter than the default size?

Comment: @SamuelSong, normally it would be with the width argument for geom_errorbar(), but this appears to only adjust the boxplot width and not the error bar as it should. An alternative would be to compute the summary and plot the geom_errorbar() with this data in the same manner.