# Is there a way to force R to create a boxplot when one of your variables has many of the same values, therefore it just plots some as points

Tags: r, boxplot

My canopy height data is very much the same values for a lot of the sites and I want to have a boxplot for these locations ( 100m & control). You can see the data here and what I am getting in R:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwSW7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIZVq.png)

```
data_long <- melt(data)
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +            
geom_boxplot()
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Location, y = value, color = variable)) +
geom_boxplot()
```

Can you force R to return it as a box and whisker rather than a line with two dots?

Comment: Hi Sean, welcome to Stack Overflow. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993545/put-whisker-ends-on-boxplot  Also, you may want to look into using a `geom_jitter()` so that your points are separated slightly.