# How can I add horizontal whiskers to the boxplots i made for my data (in R)?

Tags: r, visualization, boxplot

I have a data frame called "processed_AGB_BA" in which I want to have 2 boxplots of the data in 2 columns called: "AGB_patch_conv" and "AGB_patch_arboreal". My goal is to have a side by side comparison of the two boxplots in 1 figure, including horizontal whiskers.

This gives you an idea of how the data frame looks like:

```
> dput(head(processed_AGB_BA))
structure(list(patch_ID = c("1st near school", "SRB_OUT_01_M", 
"SRB_OUT_01_NM", "SRB_OUT_02_M", "SRB_OUT_02_NM", "SRB_OUT_21_M"
), AGB_patch_conv = c(66295.8445967275, 49135.973074405, 51484.2294385078, 
41572.738788761, 71509.7267936017, 28132.3367655501), BA_patch_conv = c(36.5263013888889, 
24.1978819444444, 27.54125, 21.865337037037, 45.5953240740741, 
14.8647916666667), AGB_patch_arboreal = c(51387.2269090947, 53555.0952762403, 
64546.2000860895, 38690.7951211127, 43723.8206226884, 25208.3905166321
), BA_patch_arboreal = c(28.2327368055556, 20.7482475974128, 
23.4128590199378, 30.5281148491577, 30.4031276527036, 12.8046908575741
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is the code that gives me partly what I want:

```
ggplot(processed_AGB_BA, aes(x = factor(1), y = AGB_patch_conv)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "transparent", color = "black", coef = 1.5) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(2), y = AGB_patch_arboreal), fill = "transparent", color = "black", coef = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "AGB [kg/ha]") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Conventional", "Arboreal Forest")) +
  ggtitle("Comparison of AGB: Conventional vs. Arboreal") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

What I do not succeed in, is getting horizontal whiskers to be added to the end of the lines (1.5 times the interquartile range). Using stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) only gives me a line across the first boxplot, and nothing on the second one (see image).

I think it has something to do with the usage of "aes(x = factor(1)...)"

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I fix this?

[image: boxplot with wrong whiskers]

Comment: Hi Arne and welcome! Thanks for providing your data and code - instead of just `head(processed_AGB_BA)`, could you edit your question to also include the output of `dput(head(processed_AGB_BA))` (it starts with `structure(...)` - this will allow us to get your exact data structure and likely lead to better, faster help. Good luck!

Comment: you might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993545/put-whisker-ends-on-boxplot

Comment: @moooh is right - you could use the combination of `stat_boxplot(geom="error bar")` and `geom_boxplot()`.  You might find it more convenient to pivot the data longer so all the values you're plotting are in the same column and the x-axis values are also a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  patch_ID = c(
    "1st near school",
    "SRB_OUT_01_M",
    "SRB_OUT_01_NM",
    "SRB_OUT_02_M",
    "SRB_OUT_02_NM",
    "SRB_OUT_21_M"
  ),
  AGB_patch_conv = c(
    66295.8445967275,
    49135.973074405,
    51484.2294385078,
    41572.738788761,
    71509.7267936017,
    28132.3367655501
  ),
  BA_patch_conv = c(
    36.5263013888889,
    24.1978819444444,
    27.54125,
    21.865337037037,
    45.5953240740741,
    14.8647916666667
  ),
  AGB_patch_arboreal = c(
    51387.2269090947,
    53555.0952762403,
    64546.2000860895,
    38690.7951211127,
    43723.8206226884,
    25208.3905166321
  ),
  BA_patch_arboreal = c(
    28.2327368055556,
    20.7482475974128,
    23.4128590199378,
    30.5281148491577,
    30.4031276527036,
    12.8046908575741
  )
) |> 
  select(AGB_patch_conv, AGB_patch_arboreal) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())
  
    
data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "transparent", color = "black", coef = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "AGB [kg/ha]") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Arboreal Forest", "Conventional")) +
  ggtitle("Comparison of AGB: Arboreal vs. Conventional") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

So, the first thing I've done is reshape the data to "long" format with `select(AGB_patch_conv, AGB_patch_arboreal) |>  pivot_longer(cols = everything())`

That means you don't have to have two calls to `geom_boxplot`, as you can supply the `aes(x = name....)` once inside `ggplot`. (`name` is the name that `pivot_wider` automatically gave to the re-shaped data labels, and `value` is the name that it gave to the column containing the values.

The important bit was provided in @moooh 's answer - use `stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")` in ggplot, and you've got the required lines on your whiskers. But it's good to have the data structured nicely for ggplot, anyway.

Specifically for your dataset, I'd probably start with:

```
data_for_graph <-
    processed_AGB_BA |> 
    select(AGB_patch_conv, AGB_patch_arboreal) |>    
    pivot_longer(cols = everything())`
```

To make the dataset for your graph, and then

```
data_for_graph |>
    ggplot(...
```

...as I've already described above

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I reshaped my data and now my boxplots look exaclty as I wanted!